# Backup SQL Server database in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, backup

I want to backup a SQL Server database with C#. I have written a stored procedure which backup the database:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE WINC_BackupDatabase
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    BACKUP DATABASE WINC_kentico
    TO DISK = 'G:\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\WINC_kentico_' + NOW() + '.bak'
    WITH NOINIT
END
GO
```

In line 10 I set the path for the backup. I want to add the current DateTime at the end of the file name. How is the syntax to set a DataTime at the end of the file name?

Best regards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
DECLARE @NAME VARCHAR(250);
SET @NAME = 'G:\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\WINC_kentico_' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),112) + '.bak';
BACKUP DATABASE WINC_kentico
TO DISK = @NAME
WITH NOINIT
```

Comment: Good call on using a cast format that does not create invalid file names (ie. ':' free).